# How to modify local url by default

Tags: reactjs, url

I'm newbie in react and I would like to know if it's possible to modify the url by default http://localhost:3000 to http://whatever.local:port_number where port_number could be whatever port.

After install react, I have modified my package.json and add this line before dependencies:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost.example:3000/"
```

But when I start the project with: *npm start* the url opened is http://localhost:3000 and not http://localhost.example:3000.

What can I do that my project start with http://localhost.example:3000 instead of http://localhost:3000?

**Edit I:**

I have created a .env file with HOST=http://local.example:3000 and I've got this error:

[image]

**Edit II:**

It doesn't work to me :(

**.env file**

[image]

**hosts file**

[image]

**ping to new host**

[image]

Comment: Which value has the `HOST` key inside your `.env` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [`.env`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration) file with the key `HOST=localhost.example` it should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you!!! But it doesn't work to me :( I have updated my original post with the result.

Comment: The host `local.example` have to be available on your machine otherwise it throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

in your `package.json` after name or version, you need to set `"homepage":"http://localhost.example:3000"` (it wouldn't work !),
but if you wanna change your url after `http://localhost:3000/....` you should write like: `"http://localhost:3000/home` (or your favorit name)"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).